# How Can a Consumer in Kafka be assigned to a Specific partition ;The partition in my case is assigned through the hash value of the Key

Tags: apache-kafka

When a partition is assigned by the Producer using a number . For eg

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, 1, "[" + LocalDateTime.now() + "]" + "Message to partition 1");
```

The number **1** second parameter defines the partition id where i want my message to be sent. So the consumer can consume this message:

```
 TopicPartition partition1 = new TopicPartition(topic, 1);
 consumer1.assign(Arrays.asList(partition1));
```

But how do i achieve this for a producer choosing a partition based on the hash of the key sent by the producer using the DefaultPartitioner. Example:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, "forpartition1", "testkey");
```

Here the key is **"forpartition1"** , how do i assign my consumer to consume from this partition generated from hash Key of **"forpartition1"**. Do i again compute the hash for that key in the consumer or are there any other ways to achieve that. I am pretty new to this technology.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information that you are new to Kafka, I am tempted to guess you are unintentionally trying an advanced use case and that is probably not what you want.

The common use case is that you publish messages to a topic. The message gets assigned a partition based on the `key` and all messages for the same key ends at the same partition.

On the consumer, you subscribe to the whole topic (without explicitly asking for a partition) and Kafka will handle the distribution of partitions between all the consumers available.

This gives you the guarantee that all messages with a specific key will be processed by the same consumer (they all go to the same partition and only one consumer handles each partition) and in the same order they were sent.

If you really want to choose the partition yourself, you can write a partitioner class and configure your producer to use it by setting `partitioner.class` configuration.

From the [Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

```
NAME
partitioner.class

DESCRIPTION
Partitioner class that implements the org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner interface.

TYPE
class

DEFAULT
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner

VALID VALUES

IMPORTANCE
medium
```

A few example tutorials on how to do it can be found online. Here's a sample for reference:

- [Write An Apache Kafka Custom Partitioner](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/06/04/write-apache-kafka-custom-partitioner/)
- [Apache Kafka
  Foundation Course - Custom Partitioner](https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/custom-partitioner/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but if my consumers subscribes to the whole topic, i wont know which consumer  would be assigned to the partition generated by that particular key, and i wont be able use my business logic on that particular consumer to process the data. Is the Custom partition logic my only option in this case?

Comment: The situation you are describing feels backwards. I would not expect you to apply different logic based on the partition. If you have different message types, you can use different topics or you can apply different logic based on the data of the message itself instead of the partition. Can update your question with more details on how you are designing your system? That would make it easier to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: @CarlosLima can we explicitly assign consumers to specific partitions and kafka doesn't rebalance in case of consumer down? and also can we get how many partitions are allotted consumers

Comment: @y_159 It is probably possible to do that but this is unlikely to be a good solution. As said above, I would not expect you to apply different logic based on the partition. If you have different message types, you can use different topics or you can apply different logic based on the data of the message itself instead of the partition. I would recommend opening a separate question and stating your problem in details. :-)